# Как получить величину скидки для контрагента?

Tags: moysklad-json-api

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

получаю данные контрагента через: online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/counterparty/…

из этого я могу получить общую сумму: `salesAmount`, настройки дисконта: `discounts`, но там нет процента который накопил контрагент. Можно конечно исходя из `salesAmount` и настроек дисконта высчитать, но вдруг это уже имеется в API

В связи с этим вопрос - как получить величину скидки для контрагента? Через JSON API 1/1

Comment: Если в вопросе будут признаки того, что Вы прежде, чем сюда написать, пытались найти решение самостоятельно, то это увеличит количество людей желающих заняться Вашей проблемой https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Александр-Муксимов получаю данные контрагента через: https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/counterparty/d66b7852-697f-11e9-9107-5048001b2d0e из этого могу получить общую сумму: salesAmount, настройки дисконта: discounts, но там нет процента который накопил контрагент. Можно конечно исходя из salesAmount и настроек дисконта высчитать, но вдруг это уже имеется в API.

Comment: Я взял на себя смелость вставить Ваш комментарий в Ваш вопрос :).

Comment: Посмотрите в доке - возможно вам поможет https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/doc/#%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B8

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, только высчитывать, на данный момент по Эмаунту+Коррекции если была.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]